# importing images as pixel-perfect from flash to Unity

Tags: unity, flash

I am not sure if this works, it just feels like it should. So I have this character in flash:
[image]

And what I want to do is import him into Unity, and making him pixel-art. (And yes, for those wondering; I am hugely inspired by Binding of Isaac at the moment.)

[image]

Is it possible to not get the "shady" pixels, and just pure colors?

Comment: clarification: you do know that the image will look aliased without those pixels? as in stairstep artifacts because the pixels are square. Is that how you want it to look?

Comment: I do believe that may be how I want it, yes. I have to admit I'm not too sure what you mean by stairstep artifacts.

Comment: Yes, exactly that!